# Printing <canvas> on paper is not sharp

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, printing-web-page

I generate a bunch of labels on a webpage using , and they show nice on the screen, but when I print on a piece of paper with my printer, they don't look sharp at all. I tried converting to image with canvas.toDataURL("image/png") but still the PNG doesn't look sharp.

Is there some technique I can use to print sharp ?

Answer (score 1):

Printers typically print at 5+ times the resolution of display screens.

So your canvas needs to be 5+ times larger than the size you want to print.

A common technique is to set the canvas element size much larger than the css size.

```
<canvas width="3332" height="2499" style="width:640px;height:480px;"></canvas>
```

**[ Add code and a Demo ]**

Here's annotated code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/eFgGd/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    // canvas related variables
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var originalCW=canvas.width;
    var originalCH=canvas.height;

    // calc ratio of screen res to print res
    // (multiply all drawings by this res ratio)
    var screenToPrintRes=300/72;

    // make the CSS size the same as the original canvas size
    canvas.style.width=originalCW+'px';
    canvas.style.height=originalCH+'px';

    // make more pixels on the canvas
    canvas.width=originalCW*screenToPrintRes;
    canvas.height=originalCH*screenToPrintRes;

    // test drawings
    ctx.lineWidth=2*screenToPrintRes;
    ctx.strokeRect(20*screenToPrintRes,10*screenToPrintRes,265*screenToPrintRes,50*screenToPrintRes);
    ctx.font=24*screenToPrintRes+'px verdana';
    ctx.fillText('Hello (at printer res)', 30*screenToPrintRes,40*screenToPrintRes);

    // print
    $("#testprint").click(function(){ window.print(); });

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="testprint">Print</button><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=150></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried something like this, but the text still prints bad. Am I missing something? <html>
<head>
 <script>
 window.setTimeout(function(){
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.font = "150px Arial";
  ctx.fillText("Hello World",20,120);
 }, 2000);
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="2700" height="1800" style="width:540px;height:360px;"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: I added example code and a demo to my answer. Cheers!